# Cross fitting with same params but differents models

Tags: modeling, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, parameterization

What is the best fitting way with 2 variables to explain ($Z_1$ and $Z_2$) depending on the same variables ($X$ and $Y$) and parameters $\theta$ but with differents models ($f$ and $g$)?

For instance: $Z_1 = f(X,Y,\theta) $ and $Z_2 = g(X,Y,\theta)$. I have an estimation of $\hat{X}$, $\hat{Y}$ and $\hat{\theta}$, and two mechanistic models $f(.)$ and $g(.)$.

I would like two regressions in the same time.
I used a GLM, GLMM and `nls()` function in `R` which work to estimate $\hat{\theta}$ for $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ one at a time.

Are Bayesian model the only way? Where may I look for?

Comment: Can you explain the way that the models can be different but the parameters the same? It sounds like you must have some very specific restrictions on the form of $f$ and $g$

Comment: @Glen_b $\theta$ is most likely the superset of the parameters of the two models, which would make sense if those are two equations of the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice treatment of linear models with vector-valued outcomes is given in [John Fox's notes](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Multivariate-Linear-Models.pdf).
The competing approaches are equation-by-equation OLS and Zellner's SUR (FGLS) estimator.

In special cases (in particular, for one that applies to you, the case of same explanatory variables in each equation), there is no gain in joint estimation over equation-by-equation OLS. Still, it is computationally easier to just stack the data matrices, and estimate the 
equation-by-equation OLS in one go as below:

```
iSampleSize = 100

x = rnorm(iSampleSize)
y = rnorm(iSampleSize)
mX = cbind(x, y)

z1 = mX %*% c(2, 3) + rnorm(iSampleSize)
z2 = mX %*% c(9, 10) + rnorm(iSampleSize)
mZ = cbind(z1, z2)

# stacked OLS
solve(t(mX)%*% mX, t(mX) %*% mZ)

# equation-by-equation OLS
coef(lm.fit(x = mX, y = z1))
coef(lm.fit(x = mX, y = z2))
```

Lastly, in the nonlinear case, you can either do equation-by-equation nonlinear least squares [NLS], or get the nonlinear SUR estimator, which is again just the FGNLS estimator. Both the SUR estimators are available in the [systemfit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/systemfit/) package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I began to explore the systemfit package as you suggest, because I'm in a non-linear case.

Comment: @Leon-Alph Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question.